# Asp.Net Web Api JWT Authorization With Identity Always Getting 401

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-identity, asp.net-roles

I'm using Asp.Net Core 5, and Asp.Net Identity with EFcore. I've followed parts of many video tutorials, advice posted here on SO and [this](https://wildermuth.com/2018/04/10/Using-JwtBearer-Authentication-in-an-API-only-ASP-NET-Core-Project) very helpful article to get my project to the point where I'm at least getting 401's. My problem is now that I can't understand why I am getting 401's. I've validated my token with my secret on jwt.io and everything tells me that it should be working, but it is not. I am at a complete loss. Enough fluff, down to business.

My Startup Class. Note: in the OnMessageReceived event context.Token is null until I set it with the authorization header.

```
//imports

namespace auto_highlighter_iam
{
    public class Startup
    {

        private readonly IConfiguration _config;
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;
        public Startup(IConfiguration config, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            _config = config;
            _env = env;
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseNpgsql(_config.GetConnectionString("AutoHighlighterIAMDev"));
            });

            IdentityBuilder iBuilder = services.AddIdentityCore<IdentityUser>(options =>
            {
                options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._ ";
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 12;
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                //options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
            });
            iBuilder = new IdentityBuilder(iBuilder.UserType, typeof(IdentityRole), iBuilder.Services)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>()
                .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
                .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<IdentityUser>>();


            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(config =>
           {
               config.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
               {
                   OnMessageReceived = context =>
                   {
                       // Interesting note here. before this next line context.Token is null, but the authorization header has the jwt
                       context.Token = context.Request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization];
                       // Although the previous line successfully set context.Token to the jwt still getting 401's

                       return Task.CompletedTask;
                   }
               };
               config.RequireHttpsMetadata = !_env.IsDevelopment();
               config.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
               {
                   ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true, //tried as false
                   IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["JWT:Secret"])),
                   ValidateIssuer = true, //tried as false
                   ValidIssuer = _config["JWT:Iss"],
                   ValidateAudience = true, //tried as false
                   ValidAudience = _config["JWT:Aud"]
               };
           });

            services.AddAuthorization();

            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "auto_highlighter_iam", Version = "v1" });

                c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Description = "Insert JWT with Bearer into field",
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
                });

                c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement {
                    {
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                        {
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference
                            {
                                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                Id = "Bearer"
                            }
                        },
                        Array.Empty<string>()
                    }
                });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, DataContext dataContext)
        {
            dataContext.Database.Migrate();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "auto_highlighter_iam v1"));
            }

            app.UseExceptionHandler("/exception");

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

My AuthorizationController. There are three endpoints. Two to test the roles I have and one that should test for any valid jwt. All of them return a 401.

```
// imports

namespace auto_highlighter_iam.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("/api-v1/[controller]")]
    public class AuthorizationController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        [Authorize(Roles = "SUPERADMIN")]
        public IActionResult TestSuperAdmin()
        {
            return Ok();
        }

        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        [Authorize(Roles = "DEFAULT")]
        public IActionResult TestDefault()
        {
            return Ok();
        }

        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        [Authorize]
        public IActionResult TestAny()
        {
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

The JWT I am testing with (pretend the token isn't expired, I've been making sure it's valid)

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJWSUVXIjoiRmFsc2UiLCJFRElUIjoiRmFsc2UiLCJERUxFVEUiOiJGYWxzZSIsIkNSRUFURSI6IkZhbHNlIiwicm9sZXMiOiJERUZBVUxUIiwibmJmIjoxNjExMTIxNTI1LCJleHAiOjE2MTExMjUxMjUsImlzcyI6ImF1dG8taGlnaGxpZ2h0ZXItaWFtIiwiYXVkIjoiYXV0by1oaWdobGlnaHRlci1mcm9udC1lbmQifQ.jnbW552pr7kylc82-4FmJJMmaeu7LQ7L48M5cdnSzuMsA1yRuts9sXUQ2_ok41SqX8mFpi7yreJJXGlE6qC1vA
```

The request I am sending

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:5000/api-v1/Authorization/TestAny' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJWSUVXIjoiRmFsc2UiLCJFRElUIjoiRmFsc2UiLCJERUxFVEUiOiJGYWxzZSIsIkNSRUFURSI6IkZhbHNlIiwicm9sZXMiOiJERUZBVUxUIiwibmJmIjoxNjExMTIwMDkzLCJleHAiOjE2MTExMjM2OTMsImlzcyI6ImF1dG8taGlnaGxpZ2h0ZXItaWFtIiwiYXVkIjoiYXV0by1oaWdobGlnaHRlci1mcm9udC1lbmQifQ.zOsNADvKGx1FYkzKLX4K53Y185dHFiM408aAjinQUQrVWQ_spXClozOAvp2glgiQkM0IwkDneB4Q_JCpQfet1g'
```

I'll be quick to provide any more info if I missed anything.

Comment: Hi @Ryan Callahan,any update about this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your middleware:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

before your `app.UseAuthorization();`

Like this :

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

**Update:**

And you need to change your request to(delete `Bearer`):

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:5000/api-v1/Authorization/TestAny' \
--header 'Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJWSUVXIjoiRmFsc2UiLCJFRElUIjoiRmFsc2UiLCJERUxFVEUiOiJGYWxzZSIsIkNSRUFURSI6IkZhbHNlIiwicm9sZXMiOiJERUZBVUxUIiwibmJmIjoxNjExMTIwMDkzLCJleHAiOjE2MTExMjM2OTMsImlzcyI6ImF1dG8taGlnaGxpZ2h0ZXItaWFtIiwiYXVkIjoiYXV0by1oaWdobGlnaHRlci1mcm9udC1lbmQifQ.zOsNADvKGx1FYkzKLX4K53Y185dHFiM408aAjinQUQrVWQ_spXClozOAvp2glgiQkM0IwkDneB4Q_JCpQfet1g'
```

Comment: Changed my configure method as such and didn't work. Really wish that was all it was.

Comment: Hi @Ryan Callahan,you can see my update answer.

Comment: sorry for the late response, but this ended up being the problem. Its surprising to me though because I thought bearer auth would need Bearer in front of it. Thank you!